# How to set value in the dataholder of fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewholder

I have made a 2nd fragment in which I have received the value from  1st fragment. But the issue is that I can't set the received to the textview of 2nd fragment.

I use the `Log.d()`; method to check, but I found that the databindholder is never called:

> Issue 1: databindholder is not called
>
> Issue 2: can't set the value to the textview of 2nd fragment

Thank you for your concern!

```
public class ListTable extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ListTable() {
//         Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static ListTable newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ListTable fragment = new ListTable();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_table, container, false);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        MyAdapter a = new MyAdapter();
//        a.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(a);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void receiveValue(String value) {

        int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("value", result);
        ListTable listTable = new ListTable();
        listTable.setArguments(bundle);
        MyAdapter b=new MyAdapter();
        b.notifyDataSetChanged();
//        a.notifiedatachanged

        Log.d("ashu", "value recived :" + value);

    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDataViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public MyDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_table, parent, false);

            return new MyDataViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if (getArguments() != null) {

                int value1 = getArguments().getInt("value");
                Log.d("ashu", "the value received inthe bindholder is " + value1);
                holder.myEditText.setText("Table is: " + position * value1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    public class MyDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView myEditText;

        public MyDataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            myEditText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_value);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the code below:

```
getFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.holder, fragment2).commit();
```

it should be added where you have made object of 2nd fragment in the receiveValue function!

```
public void receiveValue(String value) {

    int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("value", result);
    ListTable listTable = new ListTable();
    listTable.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.table_value_container, listTable).commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly declare an empty constructor, Java will do that for you if you haven't declared any other constructors.

Your whole structure is wrong, you are receiving the value in ListTable, but then you create a new ListTable instance!?

What you should do is have your activity receive the value from your first fragment (via interface) and from your activity set the value directly to ListTable if you already have a reference to it or add a new ListTable fragment with ListTable.newInstance();

Answer (score 0):

Pass you data list using constructor to `MyAdapter` and use that list to get value for each position. Like this...

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDataViewHolder> {

    private List<YourObject> items;

    public MyAdapter(List<YourObject> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public MyDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_table, parent, false);

        return new MyDataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataViewHolder holder, int position) {

        YourObject val = items.get(position);

        if(val!=null){

            //do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

And in the fragment, call like this...

```
List<YourObject> items = ..... (generate anyway you need)
MyAdapter a = new MyAdapter(items);
recyclerView.setAdapter(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Binder is not called because setArguments() is not used properly. For your case you can simply create a method in adapter and pass the value.

You should use the **setArguments** in Fragments like this

```
Fragment fragment2 = new FragmentB();
fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.holder, fragment2).commit();
```

use **getArguments** like this

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
     Bundle data = getArguments();
     if (data != null) {
        //TODO - retrieve all your data
     }
     // Create view
     // Create your adapter 
     return view;
  }

}
```